# React <Switch> is not getting updated or changing its state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

Hey guys I am learning react and have a form to edit book details. I am using django in the backend. I am not able to update the e-book which is a `switch` to turn on and off according to whether e-book is available or not. The switch works fine, but no data is being changed in the database. I am confused on how to work with the switch and saw lots of resources saying different things which is quite difficult to understand. Rest of the fields are getting updated correctly. Can someone tell me what changes I have to make in this `switch` to make it work??

code

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react'
import axiosInstance from '../../axios';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';

//MaterialUI
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import CssBaseline from '@material-ui/core/CssBaseline';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';


const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    paper: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(8),
        display: 'flex',
        flexDirection: 'column',
        alignItems: 'center',
    },
    bookformbody: {
        display: "flex",
        backgroundColor: "#ffff",
        height: "100vh",
    },
    form: {
        width: '100%', // Fix IE 11 issue.
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
    submit: {
        margin: theme.spacing(3, 0, 2),
    },
}));


function BookEdit() {    
    const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        id: '',
        summary: '',
        published_date: '',
        e_book: false,
    });

    const [formData, updateFormData] = useState(initialFormData);

    useEffect(() => {
        axiosInstance.get('api/books/details/view/').then((res) => {
            updateFormData({
                ...formData,
                ['summary']: res.data.summary,
                ['published_date']: res.data.published_date,
                                ['e_book']: res.data.e_book,

            });
            console.log(res.data);
        });
    }, [updateFormData]);

    const handleChange = (e) => {
        if(e.target.name === "e_book"){
             return(
                 updateFormData({
                     ...formData,
                     [e.target.name]: e.target.checked
                 })
                
             )
        }   
        updateFormData({
            ...formData,         
            // Trimming any whitespace
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };


    const onSubmit = (data) =>{
        let formData = new FormData();

        formData.append('summary', data.summary);
        formData.append('published_date', data.published_date);
        formData.append('e_book', data.e_book);

        axiosInstance.put('api/books/details/edit/', formData);

    } ;
    
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { register, handleSubmit, control, errors } = useForm();

    return (
        <>
            <Header />
            <div className={classes.bookformbody}>
                <SideBar />
                <Container component="main" maxWidth="sm">
                    <CssBaseline />
                    <div className={classes.paper}>
                        <Typography component="h1" variant="h5">
                            Edit Book Details
                        </Typography>
                        <form className={classes.form} noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
                            <Grid container spacing={2}>
                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        required
                                        fullWidth
                                        id="summary"
                                        label="Book Summary"
                                        name="summary"
                                        autoComplete="summary"
                                        value={formData.summary}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        inputRef={register({maxLength: 1000})}
                                        multiline
                                        rows={4}
                                    />
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <TextField
                                        variant="outlined"
                                        required
                                        fullWidth
                                        type="date"
                                        label="Published Date"
                                        name="published_date"
                                        autoComplete="published_date"
                                        value={formData.published_date}
                                        onChange={handleChange}
                                        inputRef={register({required: true})}
                                        InputLabelProps={{
                                            shrink: true,
                                          }}
                                    />
                                </Grid>

                                <Grid item xs={12}>
                                    <InputLabel id="e-book-switch">E-Book</InputLabel>
                                        <Controller
                                            name="e_book"
                                            control={control}
                                            as={
                                                <Switch size="small"
                                                    id="e-book-switch" 
                                                    type="checkbox"
                                                    name="e_book"
                                                    onChange={handleChange} 
                                                    // inputRef={register}
                                                    value={formData.e_book}
                                                    checked={formData.e_book}
                                                />
                                            }
                                        />
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                            <Button
                                type="submit"
                                fullWidth
                                variant="contained"
                                color="primary"
                                className={classes.submit}
                            >
                                Update
                            </Button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </Container>
            </div>
        </>
    )
}

export default BookEdit;
```

Comment: Shouldn't you actually pass props to switch by props of Controller? Meaning <Controller value = {formData.e_book}..., instead of directly on switch like you do.
And if you do want to pass it directly to component you would need to use "render" instead of "as" if i am not mistaken

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are passing props to Switch directly, but what you should do is to use Controller props, and Controller will then pass it down to Switch:

```
<Controller as={Switch} value={formData.e_book} ... />
```

Otherwise you need to use **render**, not **as**
This is actually described pretty good here:
https://react-hook-form.com/api/#Controller

---

**UPDATE**

Here is the sandbox where it is working fine with above changes - https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-nash-s94v0

What i did there is simply this:

```
  <Controller
  name="e_book"
  control={control}
  render={(props) => {
   return (
     <Switch
      size="small"
      id="e-book-switch"
      type="checkbox"
      name="e_book"
      onChange={handleChange}
      // inputRef={register}
      value={formData.e_book}
      checked={formData.e_book}
    />
   );
}}
```

/>

Answer (score 1):

You are initializing the value as a string at the beginning of `BookEdit()`. Try to set `initialFormData` like this:

```
const initialFormData = Object.freeze({
        id: '',
        summary: '',
        published_date: '',
        e_book: false,
    });
```

Comment: Hello the error isn't there now, but the data is not getting updated. Can you help with that?
Thanks

Comment: @prehistoricbeast Need some more data. Is `onSubmit` function called correctly? What’s the output of the line `let formData = new FormData();`? Have you tried testing the API endpoint `'api/books/details/edit/'` manually with `initialFormData` or the expected JSON output of the form?

Comment: Yes, this is my onSubmit function, and the endpoints works perfectly when I checked it in Postman.

Comment: And now, this error is showing up `Material-UI: A component is changing the default checked state of an uncontrolled SwitchBase after being initialized. To suppress this warning opt to use a controlled SwitchBase.`

Comment: @prehistoricbeast That hints that React can’t decide if you are using uncontrolled or controlled form fields. It might have nothing to do with your issue but try removing `inputRef` attributes and see what happens.

Comment: yeah, I tried, it shows the same error. even though the value from the database is true, it shows this error and shows false only, but consoling the value gives the correct data. Other fields doesn't have any problem.

Comment: @prehistoricbeast Have you uncommented the `checked` handler in `handleChange()`? If you didn’t it would behave exactly as you’ve described.

Comment: Yes, I tried in every possible way! but it just doesn't work.